# how can i print a clikible link on command in spigot api

Tags: java, minecraft

hi I'm making a plugin for Minecraft spigot and want to have it so you can type the command

`/shop`

and it while answer whit

`https://vattenfallet.tebex.io` witch is the site for the shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use Minecrafts TextComponents to send the message. Just use them like this:

```
TextComponent textComponent = new TextComponent(broadcast);
textComponent.setClickEvent(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.OPEN_URL, url));
player.sendMessage(textComponent);
```